# PHP Fatal error: Maximum execution time of -1 seconds exceeded in

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, ubuntu

Been getting this error on my server all of a sudden -

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of -1 seconds exceeded in
```

This is happening inside my wordpress site. It shows up across many files so it's not isolated to one in particular.

Googling hasn't given me any results for the "-1 seconds" issue which is rather odd. I've tried increasing the time limit on the scripts but it doesn't resolve the issue.

I've found that refreshing the page many times will eventually give me the page I want.

I ended up reinstalling Wordpress, and I get the same issue again. I'm starting to think it's not a Wordpress issue, but have no idea where to start diagnosing the issue.

Comment: Refer to [How to Fix Fatal Error: Maximum Execution Time Exceeded in WordPress](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-fatal-error-maximum-execution-time-exceeded-in-wordpress/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your php code(add top)

```
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
```

if you are getting error again and again increase the time limit and see